# "Could not load type xxx" in IIS 8.5 for IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, httpmodule

I have created an http module in ASP.NET

```
namespace aellerb.App_Code
{
  public class ContentParser : IHttpModule
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Configured in web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="ContentParser" type="aellerb.App_Code.ContentParser"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The module works and loads when run locally in IISExpress. However when I deploy it to my web host under IIS 8.5 I get:

*System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'aellerb.App_Code.ContentParser'.*

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) I found "Custom handler and module source code can be put in the App_Code folder of an application...".

So I created a folder called App_Code on the server, and copied my http module .cs file to there. It now loads and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to declare the assembly name
try this

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="ContentParser" type="aellerb.App_Code.ContentParser, {your_web_application_dllname_without_extention_name}"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: No, this was not necessary in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that anymore.